# How to traverse arrays loaded from xml into php

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file as follows:

```
<Main>
<SubMain>
  <First>10570</First>
  <Time>07:33:51</Time>
  <Result>500</Result>
  <Taken>8:14</Taken>
  <Results>
    <int>100</int>
    <int>100</int>
    <int>85</int>
    <int>100</int>
    <int>100</int>
    <int>100</int>
    <int>100</int>
  </Results>
</SubMain>
</Main>
```

That I am loading from a file into PHP using simplexml_load_file:

```
   $xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->children() as $child)
   {
        echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child->First . $child->Time . $child->Taken ."<br>";

    }
```

When I load in the Results row I am not getting any values returned, how do I step into this sub-array? Sorry if it's a daft question but has had me stumped today!

Edit:
Removed the typo since it does not exist in the code, also to be clear the First, Time, Result etc are returning the expected values, it is the sub array (Results) I can not seem to pull data from.

Comment: You have a typo in your `<FIrst>` tag

Comment: That type is in both the source and in the code.

Comment: Yeah tired eyes make mistakes, I changed the field names before posting here so they were easier to read, the error doesn't exist in the live code. Thanks for the spot though!

Comment: If you fix the typo in your note.xml file and in your code you will get a result: `SubMain: 1057007:33:518:14<br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All values returned when using SimpleXML are `SimpleXMLElement` objects, which can be cast to native types (e.g. `var_dump($xml->SubMain->First);`). It also implements `Traversable` so it can be used in foreach loops.

To get the `<int>` values, you will need to loop over the children of `<Result>`:

```
foreach ($xml->SubMain->Results->children() as $result) {
    // $result is a SimpleXMLElement object, needs casting
    var_dump(intval($result));
}
```

You can also cast directly to an array, but note that you will have an array of strings:

```
$ints = (array) $xml->SubMain->Results->int;
var_dump($ints); // actually strings
```

So you could do something like this:

```
$ints = array_map('intval', (array) $xml->SubMain->Results->int);
var_dump($ints);
```